# Use 2, 0, 1 and 8 to make 71

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, calculation-puzzle

Use all and only the digits $2,0,1,8$ once each to make the number $71$.

Allowed operations; anything not on this list is banned:

- $+,-,\times,\div, ()$ (parentheses and/or choose function)
- Concatenation; only applied to the original digits e.g $(8-1)||(2-0!)$ is not allowed
- $!$ single factorial (none of that double factorial + weird stuff otherwise you could do something like $12!!!!!!=12\times6$ and that's a bit cheat)
- Exponentiation, although the exponent must be 'made' as well
- Sqrt (free of cost); nth roots however require you to be able to make the number 'n'
- Decimal point: like concatenation, this can only be applied to the original digits. Sorry to those who attempted this before -- unlike in some questions, I'm requiring that any decimal point needs an integer part before it (wikipedia: *..used to separate the integer part from the fractional part of a number*)

---

<sub>Sorry I know PSE is being plagued with these but I couldn't resist.</sub>

Comment: how is 12!!!!!!=12×6?

Comment: @Rotsor Sextuple factorial (not allowed in this puzzle).

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος, it's just a question how does it work, mathematically.

Comment: @rus9384 It's a matter of (totally wrong, in my opinion) notation; don't try to split the $!$s to find some meaning which makes more sense. ;-)

Comment: Is $(N!)!$ allowed?

Comment: Huh, apparently that's a thing: [Multifactorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about:

> $$\sqrt{(8-1)!+2-0!} $$ I found this by chance when noticing that $71^2 = 5041$ was extremely close to $7! = 5040$.

Comment: Please hide your hint.

Comment: @HackSaw Do you mean like this?

Comment: I tried brute-forcing this using my computer, and this solution (including hundreds of variations) was the only one it could find using the rules.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Wow, thanks for confirming! I must have been extremely lucky to find this.

Comment: That is, to be more specific, any solution that does not use this strategy will likely need at least 5 unary operators (negation, factorials, square roots).

Comment: Yeah just some background to this -- (spoiler alert if you follow the link) which is kinda cool -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem

Answer (score 9):

> $$.1\times(8-2)!-0! = .1\times6!-1 = 72-1 = 71$$

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Puzzling :) I'm real sorry -- I forgot to specify that the decimal point needs an integral part before it. +1 anyway